# Globally set a word in Small Caps (or italics)

Tags: lyx, small-caps

I am using Lyx with Preamble. I am working on a project where the abbreviation "hon." needs to be set to small caps globally. (/sc). Tried to use `\renewcommand`, no luck there.

[image: example]

Comment: You might need to elaborate a bit on that. Tried to use `\renewcommand` on what exactly? Might be a good idea to provide a `MWE`.

Comment: I suspect that he tried to write `\renewcommand{hon.}{{\sc hon.}}` or something similar.

Comment: Cheers Kurts for pointing it out. @daleif I was trying what Beaudrap said, but with little success.

Answer (score 5):

I think I see what you want. In LyX, type the text "LyX" and export to pdf. You will see that it is formatted automatically. Is that what you want?

There is no user-friendly way to add your own special phrase as these (also "TeX", "LaTeX2e", "LaTeX") are hardcoded. However, if you can compile LyX, it's very easy to add your own:

(1)
Edit `src/Paragraph.cpp` and edit the `special_phrase` array as follows:

```
special_phrase const special_phrases[] = {
        { "LyX", from_ascii("\\LyX{}"), false },
        { "TeX", from_ascii("\\TeX{}"), true },
        { "LaTeX2e", from_ascii("\\LaTeXe{}"), true },
        { "LaTeX", from_ascii("\\LaTeX{}"), true },
        { "hon.", from_ascii("\\hon{}"), false },
};
```

(1.5, optional) Note that you should also change `src/tex2lyx/text.cpp` so that if you import a tex file with "hon." LyX does *not* try to change it. This is easy -- just add "hon." to the `known_phrases` and `known_coded_phrases` arrays.

(2) (re)compile.

(3) Then in your preamble put

```
\newcommand{\hon}{{\sc hon.}}
```

The reason it's a good idea to have a middleman, `\hon{}`, is so that you can easily change it in the preamble and you won't have to recompile.

That should do what you want. I'm not sure it's a good idea though. Note that if you input `Mathew is planning to run a marathon.`, the `hon.` will still be substituted for. If you're quick enough to catch that would-be error, instead of `marathon.` put `marathon[put an empty ERT box here].` and the output will be as intended.

An alternative way to the above would be to use a python script.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest approach is to use a macro specifically for "hon." wherever it appears.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand\Hon{\textsc{hon.}}
\begin{document}
Surely, if the \Hon\ Member found himself in that position \emph{etc.}
\end{document}
```

Note the backslash after the macro `\Hon`. Nearly (but not quite all) macros consume all whitespace after the occur, including any which are defined by `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` under ordinary circumstances. The backslash immediately after the macro preserves the whitespace which occurs immediately afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Beaudrap, but is there a way to change the style to small caps without modifying the original text?

Comment: if I can put it into an analogy, I would like to achieve the same function as the GREP style in InDesign.

Comment: That's not easy in LaTeX, but you can use your prefered editor to search and replace `hon.` with `\Hon` in your files.

Comment: Yes, and also note that LyX's advanced search and replace, `Edit > Find & Replace (Advanced)` might be useful here